# Access global Qt object in javascript file, QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I defined this javascript function that creates a component and checks, whether it is ready, in one of my QML files:

```
Item {
    id: lib

    function createCmpt(path) {
        var cmpt = Qt.createComponent(path)
        if (cmpt.status !== Component.Ready) {
            if (cmpt.status === Component.Error) {
                console.error("Error: " + cmpt.errorString())
            }
            console.error("Error: component not ready, path: " + path)
            return null
        }
        return cmpt
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, I would like to use this function in any of my .qml files (global usage). I know that I can declare this function at the root of my app (`ApplicationWindow` in my case). But is there a way to define this function maybe in a separate javascript file?
I tried to do that like this (`qml.js`):

```
.pragma library

function createCmpt(path) {
    var cmpt = Qt.createComponent(path)
    if (cmpt.status !== Component.Ready) {
        if (cmpt.status === Component.Error) {
            console.error("Error: " + cmpt.errorString())
        }
        console.error("Error: component not ready, path: " + path)
        return null
    }
    return cmpt
}
```

But of course this does not work, as this seems to be vanilla javascript, which has no knowledge of the global Qt object.

Any ideas, on how I could define this function in my external js file?

UPDATE: I did not read my error message carefully enough! It seems like the global Qt object is indeed known to the javascript. However, `Component` was not. In the [official doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-javascript-resource-from-a-qml-document) I found a way to import qml namespaces to javascript files and I rewrote my code to:

```
.pragma library

.import QtQml 2.11 as QtQml

function createCmpt(path) {
    var cmpt = Qt.createComponent(path)
    if (cmpt.status !== QtQml.Component.Ready) {
        if (cmpt.status === QtQml.Component.Error) {
            console.error("Error: " + cmpt.errorString())
        }
        console.error("Error: component not ready, path: " + path)
        return null
    }
    return cmpt
}
```

However, now I get an error:
`QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`
I am not sure what to do with it

Comment: Just use a singleton instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I already found the solution.
The code I posted in the update of my question is already what I need:

```
// qml.js
.pragma library

.import QtQml 2.11 as QtQml

function createCmpt(path) {
    var cmpt = Qt.createComponent(path)
    if (cmpt.status !== QtQml.Component.Ready) {
        if (cmpt.status === QtQml.Component.Error) {
            console.error("Error: " + cmpt.errorString())
        }
        console.error("Error: component not ready, path: " + path)
        return null
    }
    return cmpt
}
```

The error message with the timer no longer appears, not sure where it came from (I did some other stuff at the same time).
So this works now, I can use the Qt stuff with imports in my dedicated javascript files :)